# Missing "com" folder in .apk

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I am a student currently working on an app for a hospital. I have an old build of a working .apk but the source code that I have been working with is newer.

My problem is that when I build the apk from the newer source and look inside with winRar or apktool, there is no "com" folder (and inside of that a folder called 'iTextPDF'). The old apk has this folder.

What happens in the newer code/apk is when a graph is generated in the app and then outputted to pdf, the app crashes. The error is saying that the files don't exist.

Again, it works on the old apk but I don't have the source. I don't think that too much has changed in the code. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Try to get the old source code**

Best bet would be to get access to the old source, but I am guessing you would if you could.

**2. Try to figure out what the issue is and solve it**

First thing that pops into my head is that the apps have different package IDs, your's missing the "com.".  This is just a wild guess, though.  Given that each app must have a unique package name, if you are not working from the original source, that makes a little sense to me.

**3. You could try to reverse engineer the old code....**

Take a look at [APKTool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/), [Dex2Jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) & [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui), and [AndroGuard](https://code.google.com/p/androguard/).

APKTool will let you disassemble the APK into "smali" code.  You can look at it and modify it and use APKTool to assemble that back into an APK.

Dex2Jar will convert your APK's classes.dex file into a Jar and JD-GUI will decompile the Jar into Java-like code.  The Java-like code **probably will not compile** back into an APK

Androguard is an RE framework and is really powerful, but somewhat difficult to use.

A nice tutorial to get started RE-ing an APK can be found here: [So you want to reverse-engineer an Android app (apk)](https://kkinder.com/2011/11/27/so-you-want-to-reverse-engineer-an-android-app-apk/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem...kind of. What I did was used Apk Manager to decompile the apk. I then added the missing folder(s) and recompiled. I signed it and I was on my way.